# Avoiding spaghetti code (gamestatemanager)

Tags: oop, coding-style

I am writing a StateManager for a game (I'm using C++ and SFML, but I tried to hide language specific elements because this is a question about any OOP language).
I have a setup in which a StateManager updates the current active state. However, a State must be able to change the active state (e.g. pressing "Play" in a menu starts a PlayingState), so I keep a reference to the StateManager in my State class.

Here's an UML diagram to make things more clear.
[image: UML diagram StateManager]

As you see, StateManager and State both reference eachother.
How can I avoid spaghetticode? Should I make the StateManager a singleton class? While we're at it, should the game class be a singleton class? I could easily do this, but I don't really like other classes in my game being able to access the game class or statemanager class, even if I am the only programmer.

Comment: Can you split out the part that State needs access too? i.e. compose StateManager from more simpler contracts (interfaces)? i.e. IRenderable with update and render. Then you only give State this part of the StateManager. Also you'd want to inject this IRenderable into the state (i.e. look at Inversion of Control).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you give such an example? Do you mean that e.g. there would be another class with the changeState method, and that State has a reference to this class but not to the StateManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to design in **contracts** also known as interfaces. For example, a state (in principle) does not need access to the state machine. The *implementation* of a state may need access though. Example in C#:

```
public interface IState
{
    void Render();
    void Update();
}

public interface IStateMachine
{
    void ChangeState(IState newState);
}

public class MenuState : IState
{
    private IStateMachine _stateMachine;

    public MenuState(IStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        _stateMachine = stateMachine;
    }

    public void Render()
    {
    }

    public void Update()
    {
    }
}

public class StateMachineImplementation : IStateMachine
{
    public void ChangeState(IState newState)
    {
    }
}
```

Notice Any implementation of `IState` is unaware of any `IStateMachine` implementation, they just work on contracts. Also notice that `MenuState` is not concerned about where 'IStateMachine' comes from (Inversion of Control), it just uses it.

You could add in another function into `IStateMachine` for `GetStates()` if you needed to.

Ultimately, you use these contracts to avoid coupling; which means you can completely replace the implementation of `IStateManager` and (assuming that adheres to the contract), `MenuState` will still work fine.

Comment: If I were to have an implicit contract (I'm the only programmer and probably won't release my source code), say that a StateManager should have a ChangeState method, would that be ok too? Is there another advantage to using **contracts** other than clean design in this case?

Comment: To many to mention in a comment, but in a word: *decoupling*. Basically, you want it so you can replace the implementation of a contract and it doesn't break anything; i.e. what `MenuState` does with the `IStateManager` contract, still works. That is it in a nutshell.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with bidirectional references.  Look at Qt's parent/child model for QWidgets.  If each State can only affect one StateManager, make each State take a pointer to a StateManager "parent" in its construction, or set it later.  A StateManager can keep track of its "children" in a collection, and each child knows who its parent is, so it can inform that parent of any changes.

Edit:
I think the first thing to look at would be to break your State class up.  Currently it represents both a state and an action to change into that state.  Actions should have knowledge of a StateMachine, to tell it to change states.  States should be internal to the StateMachine.

Comment: I figured there was something wrong with it since we had to design an application for university and they told us this was the worst possible design.

Comment: Well, ideally, you'd use some kind of event-based system so a State could just scream to the world "Hey, I've changed something!", and a StateManager knows to listen to these events and respond to them.  That way a State doesn't need to have any knowledge of a StateManager or the world outside.  It just says "Hey, anyone who cares, the user wants you to play now.  Just sayin'." and leaves it at that.  It's up to other classes to listen and respond if appropriate.

That's quite beyond the scope of what you're designing though, I think.

Comment: I see how this would be a good system. However, it is indeed beyond the scope of what I'm designing. I would like the StateManager to remain as small as possible, since there probably will be only a couple of states (maybe 3 or 4). I don't want to overcomplicate the code if it's only used once and doesn't do a lot.